# Rpm goes up and down on idle

Tags: engine, idle

I buy my first real motorcycle!It is awesome but on idle rpm goes up and down.It’s scares me because it’s injector motor not chinese.Can i drive with it or thats not nice for engine?Does someone now what is possible problem?Rpm changes about 500rpm.And it’s 125cc engine!

Comment: By how much +\- 20 rpm or 200 rpm or 500 rpm?

Comment: 500rpm.And its 125cc engine

Comment: Then you should add that info to your question.