# Idle goes up and down

Tags: engine, idle, fuel-injection

I buy my first real motorcycle!It is awesome but on idle rpm goes up and down.It’s scares me because it’s injector motor not chinese.Can i drive with it or thats not nice for engine?Does someone now what is possible problem?Rpm changes about 500rpm.And it’s 125cc engine!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rpm goes up and down on idle](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/73483/rpm-goes-up-and-down-on-idle)

Comment: welcome to StackExchange, You have already asked this question. Please be kind and remove this. We will try to answer your original question asked here [link](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/73483/rpm-goes-up-and-down-on-idle)